# DoubleLinkedList adding element doesn't work and somehow it always stays empty

Tags: c++, data-structures

As I said before DoubleLinkedList always stays empty...

I have reread code. Firstly add utility seemed a bit suspicious but it looks correct for me. I have tried adding an element into the list but when I'm calling *empty()* function it always displays *True*. Given function seems right for me.

```
template <typename T>
class DoubleLinkedList; // simple class declaration

template <typename T>
class Node { // double linked list node
private:
    T data; // node element value
    Node *next; // next node in list
    Node *previous; // previous node in list

    friend DoubleLinkedList<T>; // allow DoubleLinkedList access
};

template <typename T>
class DoubleLinkedList { // doubly linked list;
public:
    DoubleLinkedList(); // constructor
    ~DoubleLinkedList(); // destructor

    bool empty() const; // is list empty?
    const T& front() const; // get front element
    const T& back() const; // get back element
    void add_front(const T& e); // add to front of list
    void add_back(const T& e); // ad to back of list
    void remove_front(); // remove from front
    void remove_back(); // remove from back
    void ordered_traverse() const;

private: // local type definitions
    // list sentinels (dummy nodes)
    Node<T>* header;
    Node<T>* tailer;

protected: // local utilities
    void add(Node<T>* v, const T& e); // insert new node before v
    void remove(Node<T>* v); // remove v node
};

template <typename T>
DoubleLinkedList<T>::DoubleLinkedList() { //constructor
    // create sentinels
    header = new Node<T>;
    tailer = new Node<T>;

    // have them point to each other
    header->next = tailer;
    tailer->previous = header;
}

template <typename T>
// destructor, removing all but sentinels; remove the sentinels
DoubleLinkedList<T>::~DoubleLinkedList() { while (!empty()) {remove_front(); delete header; delete tailer; }}

template <typename T>
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::ordered_traverse() const {
    Node<T>* cur = header->next;

    cout << "Starting Traversing... \n";

    while (cur != tailer){
        cout << cur->data << endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
// is list empty?
bool DoubleLinkedList<T>::empty() const { return header->next == tailer;}

template <typename T>
// get front element
const T& DoubleLinkedList<T>::front() const { return header->next->data; }

template <typename T>
// get back element
const T& DoubleLinkedList<T>::back() const { return tailer->previous->data; }

template <typename T>
// insert new node before v
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::add(Node<T> *v, const T &e) {
    auto* u = new Node<T>; u->data = e; // create a new node for e
    // link new node to its appropriate place
    u->next = v;
    u->previous = v->previous;
    v->previous->next = v->previous = u;
}

template <typename T>
// add to front of list
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::add_front(const T &e) { add(header->next, e);}

template <typename T>
// add to back of list
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::add_back(const T &e) { add(tailer, e);}

template <typename T>
// remove node v
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::remove(Node<T> *v) {

    if (empty())
        throw std::out_of_range("Error: list is empty... \n");


    Node<T>* u = v->previous;
    Node<T>* w = v->next;

    u->next = w;
    w->previous = u;

    delete v;
}

template <typename T>
// remove from front
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::remove_front() { remove(header->next);}

template <typename T>
// remove from back
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::remove_back() { remove(tailer->previous);}
```

I need that adding method work the way it should and if you don't mind, please give me some advice about code's other flaws which I am not able to see because of my ignorance.

Comment: Which method?  Does `add_back` work?  Have you stepped through this with a debugger?  Have you written out an example on paper and worked through what your code does by hand?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `v->previous->next = v->previous = u` looks like undefined behavior (sequence point).  Why not use `u->previous->next`, since you already saved the value of `v->previous` in `u->previous`?

Comment: Debug by drawing boxes and arrows on a piece of paper. Also, work out what to do by drawing boxes and arrows on paper.

Comment: thanks, paddy that worked ... also there was a bug in traverse but whatever I got what I wanted thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with this snippet of code

```
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::add(Node<T> *v, const T &e) {
auto* u = new Node<T>; u->data = e; // create a new node for e
// link new node to its appropriate place
u->next = v;
u->previous = v->previous
v->previous->next = v->previous = u; /* this is causing the problem */
}
```

the statement `v->previous->next = v->previous = u;` is causing the problem. The assignment operator is right to left associative. So the first assignment cause the v->previous to point to u and the whole code gets corrupted.
 You can change the statement as:

```
v->previous->next = u;
v->previous = u;
```

This may solve your problem.
Hope this helps, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ordered_traverse() will always end up in a never ending loop. You might want: `cur = cur->next;` in the while loop. That may account for why the data doesn't print?

Comment: yep thanks for saying  got that fixed already and no the problem was undefined behaviour (sequence point) as paddy said